# Catalog indexing take 3 to 4 days

Tags: magento-1.9, database, performance, indexing

I have facing problem about manual indexing from cli and my command `php indexer.php` reindexall will take 3 to 4 day to compelete the indexing.

Here is some states of current catalog.

> 1. Number of stores 4
> 2. Number of categories 300+
> 3. Number of product 40000+
> 4. Number of attributes per product 200+
> 5. Visible attribute on porduct page 150+ (create flat table about 300+ columns)

I'm importing products about every weekend about 4000+ products using mamgi tool. Every thing working fine except indexing.

Is there any other way to improve and speed up the indexing.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does the ouput of `php indexer.php reindexall` give you the time spent for each index? Have you tried to give more RAM to php https://community.magento.com/t5/Installing-Magento-1-x/Indexing-takes-not-forever/td-p/98566 ?

Comment: I didn't see output because I am running indexing in background thats y i didn't see the output

Comment: Thanks @nicolallias actually it was memory issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After spending dozens of hours, i finally got the solution.
The issue was basically limited RAM resources. 
If your system have the enough amount of memory then simple execute `indexer.php` will work.
Otherwise you need to execute it with the memory stuff. `memory_limit=-1`

like `php indexer.php -d memory_limit=-1 reindexall`